# Strategy to remove malware from EE install

Tags: ee3

A client's host has reported Malware present in a EE 3 install. I've not found anything myself, but I wondered if anyone has a strategy to deal with this. I was thinking I should upgrade to the latest version, but is it a good idea to ask the host to roll back the installation to an instance before the Malware was reported first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EE3 it is possible to completely replace the EE system files easily enough - so if you think the malware has got into the EE install itself this would be a good thing to do: if the EE3 installation is not at the latest version it would be good practice to update to that at the same time.  Instructions on how to do this [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/installation/update.html).

Another best-practice (if not done already) is to move the EE system folder out of the public_html folder (or your equivalent).  Instructions on how to do this [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/installation/best_practices.html).

However it is much more likely that the malware has not compromised the EE installation itself and is hooked in via changes to supporting files - so check your `index.php` and `admin.php` files (best practice is to replace these with clean copies from an EE install modified as required to suit your setup) and restore clean copies of any javascript files you are using from source.

HTH